# Maximum number of characters output from Win32 ToUnicode()/ToAscii()

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, ascii

What is the maximum number of characters that could be output from the Win32 functions ToUnicode()/ToAscii()?

Surely there is a sensible upper bound on what it can output given a virtual key code, scan key code, and keyboard state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Windows 8 machine `USER32!ToAscii` calls `USER32!ToUnicode` with a internal buffer and `cchBuff` set to 2. Because the output of `ToAscii` is a `LPWORD` and not a `LPSTR` we cannot assume anything about the real limits of `ToUnicode` from this investigation but we know that `ToAscii` is **always** going to output a `WORD`. The return value tells you if 0, 1 or 2 bytes of this `WORD` contains useful data.

Moving on to [`ToUnicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320(v=vs.85).aspx) and things get a bit trickier. If it returns 0 then nothing was written. If it returns 1 or [-1](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/05/18/2710448.html) then one UCS-2 code point was written. We are then left with the strange `2 <= return` expression. We can try to dissect the MSDN documentation:

> Two or more characters were written to the buffer specified by pwszBuff. The most common cause for this is that a dead-key character (accent or diacritic) stored in the keyboard layout could not be combined with the specified virtual key to form a single character. However, the buffer may contain more characters than the return value specifies. When this happens, any extra characters are invalid and should be ignored.

You could interpret this as "two or more characters were written but only two of them are valid" but then the return value should be documented as `2` and not `2 ≤ value`.

I believe there are two things going on in that sentence and we should eliminate what it calls "extra characters":

> However, the buffer may contain more characters than the return value specifies.

This just implies that the function may party on your buffer beyond what it is actually going to return as valid. This is confirmed by:

> When this happens, any extra characters are invalid and should be ignored.

This just leaves us with the unfortunate opening sentence:

> Two or more characters were written to the buffer specified by pwszBuff.

I have no problem imagining a return value of 2, it can be as simple as a base character combined with a [diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) that does not exist as a pre-composed code point.

The "or more" part could come from multiple sources. If the base character is encoded as a surrogate-pair then any additional diacritic/combining-character will push you over 2. There could simply also be more than one diacritic/combining-character on the base character. There might even be a leading LTR/RTL mark.

I don't know if it is possible to end up with all 3 conditions at the same time but I would play it safe and specify a buffer of 10 or so WCHARs. This should be well within the limits of what you can produce on a keyboard with "a single keystroke".

This is by no means a final answer but it might be the best you are going to get unless somebody from Microsoft responds.

Comment: In my experience, `ToUnicodeEx()` can return more than 2. If return value is more than 0 (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 etc) then the buffer contains that many `wchar_t` codepoints. AFAIU, there's no upper limit on this, as the keyboard layout may very well be set up to produce ligatures (arbitrarily long strings) in response to some keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

In usual dead-key case we can receive **one or two** `WCHAR`'s (if key cannot be composed with dead-key it returns two `WCHAR`'s) for one `ToUnicode` call.

But Windows also supports ligatures:

> A ligature in keyboard terminology means when a single key outputs two or more UTF-16 codepoints. Note that some languages use scripts that are outside of the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) and need to be completely realized by ligatures of surrogate pairs (two UTF-16 codepoints).

If we want to look from a **practical side of things**: [Here is a list](https://kbdlayout.info/features/ligatures) of Windows system keyboard layouts that are using ligatures.

> 51 out of 208 system layouts have ligatures

So as we can see from the tables - we can have **up to 4** `WCHAR` for one ToUnicode() call (for one keypress) **in practice**.

If we want to look from a **theoretical perspective** - we can look at `kbd.h` in Windows SDK where underlying keyboard layout structures are defined:

```cpp
/*
 * Macro for ligature with "n" characters
 */
#define TYPEDEF_LIGATURE(n) typedef struct _LIGATURE##n {     \
                                    BYTE  VirtualKey;         \
                                    WORD  ModificationNumber; \
                                    WCHAR wch[n];             \
                                } LIGATURE##n, *KBD_LONG_POINTER PLIGATURE##n;

/*
 * Table element types (for various numbers of ligatures), used
 * to facilitate static initializations of tables.
 *
 * LIGATURE1 and PLIGATURE1 are used as the generic type
 */
TYPEDEF_LIGATURE(1) // LIGATURE1, *PLIGATURE1;
TYPEDEF_LIGATURE(2) // LIGATURE2, *PLIGATURE2;
TYPEDEF_LIGATURE(3) // LIGATURE3, *PLIGATURE3;
TYPEDEF_LIGATURE(4) // LIGATURE4, *PLIGATURE4;
TYPEDEF_LIGATURE(5) // LIGATURE5, *PLIGATURE5;

typedef struct tagKbdLayer {
....

    /*
     * Ligatures
     */
    BYTE       nLgMax;
    BYTE       cbLgEntry;
    PLIGATURE1 pLigature;
....
} KBDTABLES, *KBD_LONG_POINTER PKBDTABLES;
```

- `nLgMax` here - is a size of a `LIGATURE##n.wch[n]` array (affects the size of each `pLigature` object).
- `cbLgEntry` is a number of `pLigature` objects.

So we have a `BYTE` value in `nLgMax` - and that meant that ligature size could be **up to 255** `WCHAR`'s (UTF-16 code points) **in theory**.